# Правильный 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect

Необходимо сделать редирект со следующим условием.

1. доменное имя начинается с www
2. доменная зона com

Если выполняется любое из условий отдельно или вместе то редиректить на сайт без www в зоне ru

Первый я сделал, а вот со вторым туго. А желательно чтобы это был один редирект

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)\.(ru|com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Первый вариант вызвал циклическую переадресацию, а второй именно то, что мне было нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: Нюансов много бывает. Не за что, рад помочь.